# Centralize call logic but abstract return type

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm not sure if what I am trying to do is impossible, or perhaps its the Friday before the long weekend and my brain has alredy checked out. I've tried a couple of approaches but nothing seems to get me what I am after.

BACKGROUND

I am written a small wrapper framework that uses the Apache HTTP Commons lib to interface my portal application with an external REST API. I have created a hierarchy like the following (for both request and response -- Client is the term I use here to abstract my actual end client).

```
ClientRequest (abstract)
    BaseClientRequest (abstract)
        RequestA
        RequestB
        ...
        RequestN
```

What I want to do is mirror the requests with likewise responses --

```
ClientResponse (abstract)
    BaseClientResponse (abstract)
        ResponseA
        ResponseB
        ...
        ResponseN
```

So far so good. Problem approaching. I have created a utility class called `ClientServiceUtil` and have
implemented a method called `post()` that takes a `ClientRequest` parameter, and likewise, returns a 
`ClientResponse` type. All the service calls used the same logic. The model I created even uses a generic
key-value-pair for parameters so TECHNICALLY I could get away with just the Base level classes, but it's
early stages and I am sure the logic will start to vary by service -- hence the concrete implementations.

In my post method I run the logic and as part of the process I create a `ClientResponse` object that stores
the result and returns it. Now the issue.

I have a portlet. The portlet creates a `RequestA` object and calls the `ClientServiceUtil` with it. It wants a `ResponseA` response, but what it gets back is a `ClientResponse` so I have an assignment error.

```
ResponseA response = ClientServiceUtil.post( new RequestA() );
```

... if I try to fix this with a cast then, obviously, I end up with a runtime cast exception

```
ResponseA response = (ResponseA)clientServiceUtil.post( new RequestA() );
```

Right now I am starting to think that repeating the service call logic (found in my post method) for each of the requests or splitting it up into a part call etc. are my only options. I don't really want to do that so I am hoping that someone else out there has an idea for me.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say "obviously"... `ClientServiceUtil.post` returns a `ClientResponse`, but you can't instantiate a `ClientResponse` object so it must be returning an object of one of the concrete types.  If that happens to be of type `ResponseA`, then the type cast will succeed.  If not, it won't.  So maybe there's an error in your `post` method that is returning the wrong kind of response?  Maybe I'm missing something ...

Comment: Why are you saying that I can't instantiate a ClientResponse? That is exactly what I am doing now in the ClientServiceUtil.post in order to have the one method respond to all kinds of requests (since all requests use the same call logic).

Comment: If it's abstract, you can't say `new ClientResponse ()`.  You can declare a variable of type `ClientResponse`, but when you set it, it has to be set to something of a concrete type, e.g. `ClientResponse r = new ResponseA();`.  (The only way you can say `new ClientResponse()` is if you follow it with a body in curly braces, creating a new anonymous concrete class.)  I'm assuming that you actually used the word `abstract` in the declaration of `ClientResponse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use generics, e.g.:

```
public <T, R extends ClientResponse<T>> R post(ClientRequest<T> request) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I had tried soemthing with generics ealier but I think my lack of experience with the topic might have lead me down the same path. The more I think about it the more genrics seems to make sense. Really what I have a a generic service ... and I am just creating specific types of services. I wonder, could I do something like Service<T> and the pass it a service type (like Service<Authentication> ?

Comment: I'm using a combination of a few things here with a slight change. Dumping the util class altogether amd moving the post logic into the Request<T> class. This allows me to use T to generate the correct response (Response<T> r = new Response<T>();) without having to duplicate the post code. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the request as a sort of factory to create the associated response.  Example:

```
public interface ClientRequest {
    ...
    public ClientResponse createResponseInstance();
    ...
}
```

Then, in ClientServiceUtil,

```
public ClientResponse post(ClientRequest req) {
    ...send the request...
    ClientResponse resp = req.createResponseInstance();
    ...initialize values in resp...
    return resp;
}
```

So if you have the following:

```
public class RequestA extends BaseClientRequest {
    ...
    public ClientResponse createResponseInstance() {
        return new ResponseA();
    }
    ...
}
```

then `post()` will return a `ResponseA` object when a `RequestA` is passed as a parameter.

This allows you to safely cast the response to a ResponseA.